# Can't terminate TFTP

Tags: systemd, tftp

I'm trying to better understand a behavior I see - I took control of a server that had TFTP running and am trying to turn it off. I've already ran:

`systemctl stop tftp`

`systemctl stop xinetd`

However, when stopping the tftp service it says

> Warning: Stopping tftp.service, but it can still be activated by: tftp.socket

`ss -lnpu` afterwards gives me

```
UNCONN      0      0                             :::69                                        
:::*                   users:(("systemd",pid=1,fd=60))
```

I checked and the port is indeed still listening, but the PID is listed as systemd? I don't understand the behavior - how is TFTP being run directly by systemd?

Edit: I figured out there was another "service" called tftp.socket running that kept the socket open after I killed the tftp.service. What I still don't understand is why this shows up as being part of the systmed pid.

Answer (score 0):

The tftp-server is started to handle a tftp request. As log as there is no such request, `systemd` does not start the tftp server. But there needs to be a process that listens to the incoming request on port 69, otherwise that request lands in the bitbucket.

That process is systemd.

When a requests on port 69 comes in, systemd forks-off a tftp server to handle the request. When the tftp server is finished, it just dies.

Comment: In other words, systemd behaves just like the xinetd service which OP mentioned...

Comment: Did he? The only mentioning of xinetd in the question that I have seen is that he used `systemctl stop xinetd`.  But then, the OP edited the question, so he might have taken it out before I read it.

Comment: You're correct - I'm not using xinetd. I just stopped it. The only change I made with the edit is the indicated.